# How to move to last formfield in order to end formflow and start new intent

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

In the form flow after assisting user, assume Bot asking my user, "Is there anything else I can assist, Say yes or no" in the form field. If user says yes, I have to start again new intent which is greeting dialogue. Is it possible with form flow?

In the `BuildForm` method, Instead of setting `UserWantToCompleteEndOption` as next method to get executed, I want to complete the form flow, and look for new luis intent which is greeting dialogue.

```
.Field(nameof(UserWantToComplete), state => state.ReportRequest.Contains("UserWantToComplete"))
                .Field(new FieldReflector<SoftwareRequestWithName>(nameof(UserWantToComplete))
                            .SetActive(state => state.AskToChooseReport)
                            .SetNext(UserWantToCompleteEndOption))
```

Answer (score 1):

For stop filling the form you can use FormFlow's feature quit. You can find details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#handling-quit-and-exceptions).

Basically when you enter the word 'quit', the bot throw an exception FormCanceledException which can be caught in the method you call after your form is filled.

**Root Dialog**

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
        CustomerDetails form = new CustomerDetails();
        FormDialog<CustomerDetails> customerForm = new FormDialog<CustomerDetails>(form, CustomerDetails.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
        context.Call(customerForm, FormSubmitted);
}
public async Task FormSubmitted(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<CustomerDetails> result)
{
        try
        {
            var form = await result;

        }
        catch (FormCanceledException<CustomerDetails> e)
        {
            string reply;
            if (e.InnerException == null)
            {
                reply = $"Thanks for filling out the form.";
            }
            else
            {
                reply = $"Sorry, I've had a short circuit.  Please try again.";
            }
            context.Done(true);
            await context.PostAsync(reply);
        }
 }
```

If you want you can implement the same in your LUIS dialog.

Comment: I have updated my question to be more specific. Can you please help me now?

Comment: What is UserWantToComplete ? Could you provide the code of your form flow.

Comment: Assume I am asking my user, "Is there anything else I can assist, Say yes or no" in the form field. If user says yes, I have to start again my new intent. Is it possible with form flow?

Comment: If the user types yes then you need to refill your form or you need to fill rest of the form ?

Comment: Say user asking question about where is mail room, bot answers it and ask Is there anything else I can assist, Say yes or no?. Then user say yes . In this case bot has to restart with greeting dialogue again.